# Minimum for a nonlinear heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, maximum-principle

I'm trying to solve [question 4.6](https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/pluginfile.php/82388/mod_resource/content/0/Problem%20Sheet%204.pdf#page=3) using [maximum principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_principle)

> Suppose that $u(x, t)>0$ solves $$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(u \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)+u $$ in a region $D$ bounded by the lines $t=0$ and $t=\tau$
> and two non-intersecting smooth curves $C_1$ and $C_2$.
>
> Prove that if
> a solution exists then $u(x, t)$ attains its minimum value on $t=0$ or
> on one of the curves $C_1$ and $C_2$.

### My working

Let
$$
∂_P D=(\left[a_1, a_2\right] ×\{0\})∪C_1∪C_2.
$$
Since $D$ is compact, a continuous function $u$ has a minimum point in $D$.
First suppose $u>0$ and $∂_tu>∂_x(u∂_xu)+u=(∂_xu)^2+u∂_{xx}u+u$
If $u(x,t)$ has an internal minimum, then at this point
$$∂_xu=∂_tu=0 ∂_{xx}u≥0$$
If $u(x,t)$ has a minimum at a point on $t=τ$, then at this point
$$∂_xu=0 ∂_tu≤0 ∂_{xx}u≥0$$
Both contradicts $∂_tu>∂_x(u∂_xu)+u$ and it follows that minimum point of $u$ must be on $∂_PD$.

---

Suppose now that $∂_tu=∂_x(u∂_xu)+u$, then define $v(x,t)=u(x,t)-ϵ$ for $ϵ>0$.
Then $v$ satisfies
$$\tag1
∂_tv-∂_x(v∂_xv)-v=[∂_tu-∂_x(u∂_xu)-u]+(1+∂_{xx}u)ϵ>0$$
By the first part, the minimum point of $v$ is on $∂_PD$.
$$u>v≥\min_{∂_PD}u-ϵ$$
Let $ϵ→0$ we conclude that $u$ takes its minimum on $∂_PD$.

---

But my solution has a flaw: in $(1)$ why do we have $1+∂_{xx}u\ge0$ ?

I find a similar question: [Maximum principle for a nonlinear heat equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991122)

---

Below is Theorem 4.3. in $\S$4.4.2 [The maximum principle for heat equation](https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/pluginfile.php/30048/mod_resource/content/16/DE1notes22-11-09.pdf#subsubsection.4.4.2)

> Suppose that $u(x, t)$ satisfies $$
> u_t-u_{x x} \leq 0
> $$
> in a region $D_\tau$ bounded by the lines $t=0, t=\tau>0$, and two non-intersecting smooth curves $C_1$ and $C_2$ that are nowhere parallel to the x-axis. Suppose also that $f \leq 0$ in $D_\tau$. Then $u$ takes its maximum value either on $t=0$ or on one of the curves $C_1$ or $C_2$.

Proof:
We first observe that since $u$ is a continuous function on a compact set $\bar{D}_\tau$ it will achieve its maximum on $\bar{D}_\tau$

Suppose first that $u_t-u_{x x}<0$ in $D_\tau$. At an internal maximum inside $D_\tau, u$ must satisfy
$$
u_x=u_t=0 u_{x x} \leq 0,\left(u_{t t} \leq 0\right)
$$
On the other hand, if $u$ has a maximum at a point on $t=\tau$, then there it must satisfy
$$
u_x=0, u_t \geq 0, u_{x x} \leq 0
$$
With $u_t-u_{x x}$ assumed to be strictly negative, both of these lead to contradictions, and it follows that $u$ must take its maximum value somewhere on $\partial D_\tau$ but not on $t=\tau$. We are done.
Suppose now that $u_t-u_{x x} \leq 0$, then define
$$
v(x, t)=u(x, t)+\frac{\epsilon}{2} x^2
$$
where $\epsilon$ is a positive constant. Then $v$ satisfies
$$
v_t-v_{x x}=u_t-u_{x x}-\epsilon<0
$$
in $D_\tau$. So by the earlier step $v$ takes its maximum value on $\partial D_\tau$ but not on $t=\tau$. Now if the maximum value of $u$ over these three portions of $\partial D_\tau$ is $M$, and the maximum value of $|x|$ on $C_1$ and $C_2$ is $L$, then
$$
u \leq v \leq \frac{L^2 \epsilon}{2}+M
$$
Now we let $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ and conclude that $u \leq M$, i.e. $\mathrm{u}$ takes its maximum value on $\partial D_\tau$ but not on $t=\tau.\quad\square$

If $u_t-u_{x x} \geq 0$ in $D_\tau$, then a similar argument shows that $u$ attains its minimum value on $\partial D_\tau$ but not on $t=\tau$. Thus, for the homogeneous equation (the heat equation) $u$ attains both its maximum and its minimum values on $\partial D_\tau$ but not on $t=\tau$

Comment: @Gonçalo Because the second part applies the first part to $v$ and I want $v$ to satisfy $>0$.

Comment: @Gonçalo Now I understand your proof. Thanks.

Comment: First of all, I think your domain D is less general than in the exercise, where the domain is bounded by smooth curves and not just straight lines. Moreover, I think for this specific example you don't need the second part of the proof. In your first part you already show that the minimum can not be in the interior.

Comment: @SC2020 Yes, I will edit the post so that the domain D is same as in the exercise.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer or is it clear now?

Comment: @SC2020 It is clear to me now :)